# Sending @Value annotated fields to a DTO layer returns null

Tags: spring-boot

I have a class which is composed of 2 different objects :

```
public class MyClass{
    private OptionClass optionClass;
    private ConstantClass constantClass;


    public DocumentToSignRestRequest(OptionClass optionClass, ConstantClass constantClass) {
        this.optionClass= optionClass;
        this.constantClass= constantClass;
    }
}
```

My first class is a classic POJO. My second class retrieve values from the application.properties file.

```
public class ConstantClass {
    @Value("${api.url}")
    private String hostName;
    @Value("${sign.path}")
    private String pathStart;

    public ConstantClass () {
        this.hostName= getHostName();
        this.path = getPath();
    }
```

I map MyClass with MyClassDto in order to call a service.

```
@PostMapping(
        value="/sign",
        consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE },
        produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }
    )
public MyClassRest prepareDocument(@RequestBody DocumentToPrepare documentToPrepare) throws Exception {

    MyClassRest returnValue = new MyClassRest ();

    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    MyClassDto myClassDto = modelMapper.map(documentToPrepare, MyClassDto .class);

    DocumentDto signedDocument = documentService.signDocument(documentDto);
    returnValue = modelMapper.map(signedDocument, DocumentRest.class);

    return returnValue;
}
```

My DTO class work fine and retrieve the OptionClass datas, but concerning the second Class, i obtain null as value, while i try to print it out in the service layer.

Comment: `ConstantClass` doesn't seem to be a Spring bean. That is, it doesn't seem to be instantiated and managed by Spring.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. You mean i should annotate it as a component then ?

Comment: I mean the fields of such class shouldn't be annotated with `@Value`.

Comment: Or annotate your '@Values' with '@Transient'

Comment: If the mapper is a Spring bean, it could have fields annotated with `@Value` and then assign those values to the mapped object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ConstantClass` should be a `Bean` or a `Component` (*as @cassiomolin says in comments*)

```java
@Component
public class ConstantClass {

   private String hostName;
   private String pathStart;

   public ConstantClass (@Value("${api.url}") String url, @Value("${sign.path}") String path ) {
        this.hostName = url;
        this.pathStart = path;
   }

   // getters...
```

Then you can easily inject this component in your `Controller` and use it.

```java
@Controller
public class YourController(){

   private ConstantClass constantClass;

   public YourController(ConstantClass constantClass){
       this.constantClass = constantClass;
   }

   @PostMapping("...")
   public MyClass post(.....){
         .....
         MyClass myclass = new MyClass(this.constantClass,...)
         .....
   }

}
```

note that Spring can autowire `@Value` and `@Component`, ... via the constructor; that can be very useful when you do unit-testing

Comment: Thanks i was really stuck and it worked fine. In fact I just add to set it in the controller. I still have a long way to work before mastering this !